# Approximation in Integration

Tags: calculus

Is it always true that for small value of c i.e $c\approx 0$
$\int_0^c f(x)dx \approx \int_0^c f1(x)dx $

where $f1(x)$ is the approximate function for $f(x)$ when x is small?
For an example:
$\int_0^{0.18}(1-\sin x \cos x)dx=0.163974$.
$\int_0^{0.18}(1-x)dx=0.1638$.

In this case both are approximately same  but is it always true for any function?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “the approximate function”?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang like for $x \approx 0$ $\sin x \approx x$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples, I'm guessing that your $f1(x)$ is a linear approximation to $f$ around $a=0$:
$$
    f1(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x
$$
Of course, we have to assume $f$ is differentiable at $0$ to make this approximation.  What you're asking about is equivalent to whether
$$
    \int_0^c |f(x)-f1(x)|\,dx \approx 0
$$
when $c$ is small.

As long as $f$ is integrable, this seems true.  If $g$ is integrable, it must be bounded.  If $m \leq g(x) \leq M$ on $[a,b]$, then 
$$
    m(b-a) \leq \int_a^b g(x)\,dx \leq M(b-a) 
$$

Since $f-f1$ is also bounded, we must have
$$
    0 \leq \int_0^c |f(x)-f1(x)|\,dx \leq Mc 
$$
which tends to zero as $c\to 0$.

We can say more.  We claim $\frac{1}{c}\int_0^c(f(x)-f1(x))\,dx \to 0$ as $c\to 0$.  If you define
$$
    F(c) = \int_0^c (f(x)-f1(x))\,dx
$$
Then $F'(0) = \lim_{c\to 0} \frac{1}{c} \int_0^c(f(x)-f1(x))\,dx$.  But by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this is $f(0) - f1(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\left | \int_0^c f(x)dx - \int_0^c f1(x)dx \right | \le \int_0^c |f(x)-f1(x)|dx \le |c| \max_{x \in [0,c]}( f(x)-f1(x))$ so if the approximation is good the difference will be small.  The last inequality can be quite good if the functions are slowly varying over the region of interest.   You can have a large fractional error if the integral of $f(x)$ is rather small.